# Permission denied - running script

Tags: 12.04, permissions, scripts

I am new somewhat to scripting in Ubuntu and I have the following script which I am executing but getting back Permission Denied messages. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here's the sequence:

The Script:

```
!/tm/local/bin/bash
blockdev --setra 16384 /dev/sd[bcdefghijkl]
echo 1024 > /sys/block/sdb/queue/read_ahead_kb
echo 1024 > /sys/block/sdc/queue/read_ahead_kb
echo 1024 > /sys/block/sdd/queue/read_ahead_kb
echo 1024 > /sys/block/sde/queue/read_ahead_kb
echo 1024 > /sys/block/sdf/queue/read_ahead_kb
echo 1024 > /sys/block/sdg/queue/read_ahead_kb
echo 1024 > /sys/block/sdh/queue/read_ahead_kb
echo 1024 > /sys/block/sdi/queue/read_ahead_kb
echo 1024 > /sys/block/sdj/queue/read_ahead_kb
echo 1024 > /sys/block/sdk/queue/read_ahead_kb
echo 256 > /sys/block/sdb/queue/nr_requests
echo 256 > /sys/block/sdc/queue/nr_requests
echo 256 > /sys/block/sdd/queue/nr_requests
echo 256 > /sys/block/sde/queue/nr_requests
echo 256 > /sys/block/sdf/queue/nr_requests
echo 256 > /sys/block/sdg/queue/nr_requests
echo 256 > /sys/block/sdh/queue/nr_requests
echo 256 > /sys/block/sdi/queue/nr_requests
echo 256 > /sys/block/sdj/queue/nr_requests
echo 256 > /sys/block/sdk/queue/nr_requests
# Set read-ahead.
echo "Setting read-ahead to 64 MiB for /dev/md0"
blockdev --setra 65536 /dev/md0
# Set stripe-cache_size for RAID6.
echo "Setting stripe_cache_size to 16 MiB for /dev/md0"
echo 16384 > /sys/block/md0/md/stripe_cache_size
echo 8192 > /sys/block/md0/md/stripe_cache_active
# Disable NCQ on all disks.
echo "Disabling NCQ on all disks..."
echo 1 > /sys/block/sdb/device/queue_depth
echo 1 > /sys/block/sdc/device/queue_depth
echo 1 > /sys/block/sdd/device/queue_depth
echo 1 > /sys/block/sde/device/queue_depth
echo 1 > /sys/block/sdf/device/queue_depth
echo 1 > /sys/block/sdg/device/queue_depth
echo 1 > /sys/block/sdh/device/queue_depth
echo 1 > /sys/block/sdi/device/queue_depth
echo 1 > /sys/block/sdj/device/queue_depth
echo 1 > /sys/block/sdk/device/queue_depth
```

I gave everyone execution access like this:

```
chmod a+x /home/tm/raid-sync.sh
```

I execute it like this:

```
root@LSERVER:~# sh /home/tm/raid-sync.sh
```

It returns this:

```
/home/tm/raid-sync.sh: 1: /home/tm/raid-sync.sh: !/tm/local/bin/bash: not found
Setting read-ahead to 64 MiB for /dev/md0
Setting stripe_cache_size to 16 MiB for /dev/md0
/home/tm/raid-sync.sh: 29: /home/tm/raid-sync.sh: cannot create /sys/block/md0/md/stripe_cache_active: Permission denied
Disabling NCQ on all disks...
```

Comment: In the first line. Did you forget `#` at the start or is it intended?

Comment: Oh Wait. In first line, you wanted to use `bash` and then you are executing the script with `sh`?

Comment: Hi guys, sorry newbie mistake. You are right, I needed the #

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to escape by first error (`!/tm/local/bin/bash: not found`), change `!/tm/local/bin/bash` with `#!/bin/bash`. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) more about shebang (what it is, how to use it, examples).

Second, if you set executing permissions to the script, then run it only using `/home/tm/raid-sync.sh` at the prompt (without `sh` in front).

Third, the `/sys` directory in Linux is deceptive. Unlike most other directories, it does not provide persistent storage for arbitrary files and because of this you don't have permission to write even if you are root. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/617519/221259) for more info.

Comment: Hi Radu, many thanks for this! I followed your suggestions and got most of it working except for "echo 8192 > /sys/block/md0/md/stripe_cache_active" which still shows up as Permission denied (although the changes on other config / sys directories worked). Why not on this particular step? Thanks again!

Comment: This file: `/sys/block/md0/md/stripe_cache_active` exists?

Comment: Yes, it does - "-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Mar 17 17:03 stripe_cache_active"

Comment: @TheRealPapa As you can see, this file doesn't has write permission (`w` indicator) for anybody, including the owner which is root. The file has only read permission for all (`r` indicator).

Comment: ah! got it. I pulled the script from here to speed up my array resync... wonder why the people in this post were using this command... http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-raid-increase-resync-rebuild-speed.html

Answer (score 0):

your first line seems to have an error in it. (as seen from your error), I would start by fixing it,  maybe change it to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

then try again, and we can look at next error

Comment: no worries, I see Radu gave you a fuller answer, good to see that your problem is progressing.